# What is the difference between $('[data-target=""]') and $('[data-target*=""]')?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to understand why does `$('[data-target=""]')` is returning me some object while `$('[data-target*=""]')` isn't ?

Is there a way to target every element which has the `data-target` attribute ?

Comment: first one would only get you data-target="" not anything else like data-target="foo"

Comment: These questions are all answered in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('[data-target=""]')` matches all elements with an *empty* data-target attribute.

`$('[data-target*=""]')` is sort of a weird edge case: normally `[foo*="bar"]` would match elements with a foo attribute whose contents have 'bar' as a substring -- but if you don't include a substring to match, it won't match anything at all.

If you want to match all elements with a data-target attribute, you want `$('[data-target]')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try plain old:

```
$('[data-target]')
```

Comment: Waow didnt knew there was this kind of selector !

Comment: Woot woot @Baldráni!

Answer (score 1):

`$('[data-target=""]')` will return all elements whose `data-target` attribute is set to "". In order to target every element which has the `data-target` attribute (regardless of value), you should do `$('[data-target]')`.

Comment: But why does the second one not return me every element since it shall fulfil the condition?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If it's possible, could you post an example with HTML that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Why does `$('[data-target*=""]')` is not equal to `$('[data-target]')` ?